# Setting up Raspberry Pi detection of multiple FSRs

Tags: sensor, resistors, raspberry-pi

I am trying to start a home project with a raspberry pi. I want to link a number of [these force-sensitive resistors](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9376) up

[image: square force resistor]

The issue is i really want to assign some form of id so i can tell which has been triggered. Can you get sensors with this ability or is there someway i can add a chip or something :$

I literally have no idea and am just messing about at home - so hopefully someone can lend some helpful advice!

Comment: Do you need analog input on how much force is applied, or merely an on-off indication as suggested by your use of the word "triggered"?

Comment: no all i need to determine is whether the sensor has had pressure added or not

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a multi channel ADC chip with enough channels for all your FSRs

One example, using the 8-channel MCP3008, is shown in this [Adafruit tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi.pdf) which mentions FSRs.

Comment: Can we add 30 FSRs to Raspberry pi using MCP3008?